# File Transfer across AWS Instnaces

Tags: amazon-ec2

How can I transfer files across AWS Linux instances? Both the instances use a password file for authentication.

Is there any specific way to do this?

Please suggest me in this regards.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not to configure password less login between your servers in AWS based on Key authentication and then you can use SCP or Rsync.Below are the steps to setup password less login between two servers

Source Server (or local system)
Generate RSA key for user on this system, you can also use DSA.  This asks for key pass-phrase but you can leave it blank.

```
  ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

This asks for location to place the generated key, by default it will be your home directory (ex: /home/your_username/.ssh/).  This generates two files:  id_rsa and id_rsa.pub.  Content of id_rsa.pub is what we need to copy to destination server.

```
  Destination Server (or remote server)
```

Check if you have the directory .ssh on your home (ex: /home/username/.ssh/), if not, create that directory.

```
  ls  ~/.ssh
  mkdir  ~/.ssh
```

Check if you have existing file authorized_keys on your .ssh directory, if not create it.

```
  ls  ~/.ssh/ authorized_keys
  touch   ~/.ssh/ authorized_keys
```

Copy content of id_rsa.pub that you created from your source/local server, or execute this command from your source/local server:

```
  scp  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub username@remote_host:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have set up your SSH keys. Install RSYNC using your package manager

```
apt-get install rsync (Ubuntu)
yum install rsync (Centos)
```

You can then use RSYNC to copy (Synchronise) the files with this command

```
rsync -e 'ssh -p 9999' -avl --delete --stats --progress demo@999.45.67.890:/home/demo /backup
```

where 9999 is the port number. SSH bydefault uses port 22 if you have setup a different port mention it here.

and 'demo' is your user name on the source server.

and '999.45.67.890' is the ip address of your source server

and '/home/demo' is the directory on your source server you want to backup/synchronise

and /backup is the directory on the destination server

Comment: RSYNC should be installed on both the source and destination machines.